# How to select the columns dynamically and make total of all sizes in myql

Tags: mysql

I am facing one problem for making columns dynamic and want the count of qty. i am getting all sizes statically but i want to make dynamic. firstly i will share my code :-

```
SELECT order_products.product_name,
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = 'S' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS S,
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = 'M' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS M,
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = 'XL' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS XL,
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = '2XL' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS '2XL',
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = '3XL' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS '3XL',
max(CASE 
WHEN 
order_product_sizes.size = '4XL' THEN  order_product_sizes.qty    
END) AS '4XL',
from order_products join order_product_sizes
on order_product_sizes.order_product_id = order_products.id
group by order_product_sizes.order_product_id
```

[image]

I also want the total of all sizes in total column. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(IF(size = ''',
          size,
          ''', qty, NULL)) AS ',
          size
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM order_products_sizes;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT order_products.product_name, ', @sql, ' ,sum(qty) as total
                       FROM order_products join order_products_sizes
    on order_products_sizes.order_product_id = order_products.id
    group by order_products_sizes.order_product_id');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro... i will accept answer in few minutes as they not allow me to accept before 10 mins